# Is it possible to get the html produced by a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a URL from a third party site which should be the source of a script tag, something like this:

```
<script src="<%= @url %>"></script>
```

The above code shows a webform.

I would like to get the html code resulted by that code and store into a variable, something like this :

```
html_code = get_html('<script src="<%= @url %>"></script>')
```

Is that possible using Ruby/Rails (maybe using nokogiri) ?

Comment: Do you want to prevent the code from running and just view it or do you mind if it run? Or are you looking for the html that that code produced?

Comment: @FelesMortis yes I am looking for the html that the code produced, I want to affect that code to a variable, see my question and let me know if it's clear :)

Comment: There's two ways html can get generated(for the most part). It can be via document.write which writes html(or other data) to the place were the script is, in which case you can look there using javascript (or ruby/rails if you're more comfortable with that. The other way is by modifying the html of other elements on the page. Adding/Removing/Changing. This is harder to find, but I'd recommend taking getting the html of the page `$('html').html()` then running the script, then getting the html again and scanning for differences.

Comment: @FelesMortis yes this approach is already suggested by tadman and it works, but I want to do that directly in the server side using Rails (without hitting the browser!)

Comment: If you want to do it on the server, I think you need to a server-side browser, something like http://phantomjs.org/. It used in ruby testing frameworks such as   https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist.

Comment: @medBo That mostly depends on what the script needs. It probably needs info from your browser/the rest of the page. Then you'll want to use Derek's solution. Otherwise you can get a javascript compiler to run it and capture the output. You'll have to look at the script to be sure, but I'm reasonably certain that you'll need the server-side browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery in the browser and that code shows up in a well defined location, for example a `<div>` with a specific `id` then you can just grab it using your browser's JavaScript console:

```
$('#the_id').html()
```

That will show the raw HTML of that element presuming it dumps its content in an element with the ID `the_id`. You can use whatever CSS selector works.

Where that HTML goes in your document is impossible to tell from your example. A `<script>` can add any elements it wants anywhere in your document. You'll have to look around to see where it goes.

Comment: can I do this using ruby ? I updated my question to be more clear, thanks

Comment: Technically yes, but practically no. It involves running [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) inside Ruby as [a gem](https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem) and a whole lot of hoping and praying that your headless browser will behave the same way as a real client. Ruby itself has no way of understanding JavaScript or emulating the browser environment that it runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Load the page into a browser and then do View/Source in the browser.  This will let you view the generated web page and you can find what URL was put into the `<script>` tag.